# Advantage of Multiple parallel Http requests

Tags: java, android, http, networking, web

What actually happens when we create multiple connections/request?.How is it faster when compared to sequential request, i have this question because in case of parallel request isnt the bandwidth shared acros the requests resulting in  long response time.

In my case we multiple request on different threads using volley library but how is it useful.

Can some one explain how and why parallel requests is preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So say you're standing in a field with a baseball and three of your friends.

You want to throw the ball to each of your friends, so you throw the ball to your first friend.  He throws it back.  Then you throw the ball to your second friend, he throws it back, then your third friend, etc.

Now let's say you're standing in a field with *three* baseballs and three of your friends.

You throw one ball to your first friend.  Now that ball is in the air, so you pick up another ball and throw it to your second friend.  While *that* ball is in the air, you throw the last one to your third friend.

It's easy to see that by having multiple balls in the air at the same time, the entire process will take a lot less time.   Same principle applies to HTTP requests.  Obviously as you stated, you have to be able to have multiple connections and multiple threads; however, when you can do that, you will get the same amount of work done in a shorter time.

Answer (score 6):

There are at least three reasons that I can think of: latency, packet loss, and traffic shaping.

1. **Latency:** A lot of what makes many network connections (and particularly cellular connections) slow is latency—the amount of time it takes for a request to make a round trip to the server.  Suppose you send five requests and each request takes one second for the request to reach the server and for the response to come back.  If you send all five requests sequentially:

   ```
   0   1   2   3   4   5
    RQ1 RQ2 RQ3 RQ4 RQ5|
   ```

   then it takes five seconds.  Suppose you instead send them one right after the next.

   ```
   0   1   2   3   4   5
    RQ1    |
     RQ2   |
      RQ3  |
       RQ4 |
        RQ5|
   ```

   This takes much less time, because the device can be transmitting the next request while the previous one is still in flight.
2. **Packet loss:** Another cause of slowness (again, particularly with cellular and Wi-Fi networks) is packet loss.  TCP typically uses a congestion control technique to avoid causing excessive packet loss if a network link (wire between two routers) is saturated (at capacity).  When the OS detects the loss of a packet, it pauses the outgoing stream of packets, then slowly starts sending packets again (including retransmitting the dropped packet), getting faster and faster until a packet gets lost, then backs off again, and so on.

   Because this backoff process happens independently for each open TCP socket, if you have multiple simultaneous sockets open, a dropped packet on one socket will have no impact on the other sockets.  Thus, requests won't get delayed arbitrarily by packet loss that occurs during other requests.
3. **Traffic shaping:** Often, ISPs shape traffic to prioritize interactive traffic over downloads.  This results in each network connection being very fast at first, then slowing to a crawl after a certain amount of time or after a certain amount of data is transmitted.

   By making multiple requests in parallel on multiple connections, you take that time penalty simultaneously instead of consecutively.

The upshot of all this is that folks try to design network protocols to minimize the number of round trips, to try to keep multiple requests in flight simultaneously, and to minimize dependencies between requests (sending requests B and C based on the response from request A) as much as possible.

For example, when you're writing a web browser, you begin fetching images and CSS as soon as you've gotten a partial parse of the HTML sufficient to tell you that a given image or CSS file needs to be loaded.  The sooner you start each of those dependent requests, the less time it takes to load the page as a whole and render it.